# Using locks in python multiprocessing does not work

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to test the lock functionality in Python multiprocessing. Here is my code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock

def fn(N,q,l):
    l.acquire()
    for i in range(N, N+500):
        q.put(i)
    l.release()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    q = Queue()
    l = Lock()
    p1 = Process(target=fn, args = (0,q,l,))
    p2 = Process(target=fn, args = (500,q,l,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    while(q.empty() == 0):
        print(q.get(), end=" ")
```

I am using a Queue object to put in numbers from 1 to 1000 using two processes and then printing them out in the same order. I am using a lock to make sure the insertion order stays in ascending order and does not get jumbled up. However on popping from the queue, the output is in jumbled up order and not from 1 to 1000 in ascending order as I had expected.

Is the lock in one process not preventing the other process from writing to the queue?
Or is there an issue with the usage?

Comment: Or you can not bother with manual lock management and instead use higher-level primitives such as `.map()`, which guarantee order (unless you explicitly don't want that, see `.imap_unordered()`).

Comment: When I try your code, it *does* print all the numbers in sequence. This is on FreeBSD (UNIX), with Python 3.7.7.

Comment: @RolandSmith On ubuntu 16.04 with Python 3.7.3, I have found that it does print in sequence a couple of times but then breaks on further runs. The behavior is not consistent.

Comment: @user3679673 Try with the latest Python version (3.8.2). If that still exhibits this behavior, [file a bug report](https://bugs.python.org/).